# How to create custom tab bar under navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have to create a tab bar on top of my view ([screenshot](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2dwf9k2.jpg)). I have found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264464/xcode-6-swift-custom-tabbar-with-navigation) where someone has the same problem. But it's hard for me to understand what should I code for the 3.1 chapter of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264464/xcode-6-swift-custom-tabbar-with-navigation#answer-29265054). Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to move tabbar to top.

As Alternative this link solve your problem definitely

[https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu](http://Link)

Comment: Thank you for this link, I will look it later.